# Rolling back a complete transaction

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule, database, database.insert

I have two object `foo__c` and `zoo__c`. zoo__c is a child of foo__c with a master detail relationship. I have validation rule created on Zoo__c with a condition that when the `status__c` field on related `Foo__c` object is `'Open`' then throw an error. => `Foo__r.status__c== 'Open'`

I wrote a trigger on `Foo__c` , which creates a new `zoo__c` record whenever `foo__c` is updated. Below is my logic in trigger:

```
trigger footrigger on Foo__c (after insert,after update) {

       if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
       List<zoo__c> zlist = new List<zoo__c>();
            For(Foo__C f : trigger.new){
              Zoo__c z = new Zoo__c();
              z.Foo__c = f.id;
              z.Name='AZooObj'; 
              zlist.add(z);
            }
        Database.insert(zlist,false);
       }
    }
```

Note I use `Database.Insert` to pass the records. Hence the records that meets validation rule on `zoo__c` should create a new `zoo__c` record and fail the one which does not meet the rule.

The Problem : When I update a `foo__c` record from UI which has its `status__c` field as `'Open'`, the validation rule does not kick in and it updates the `foo__c` record without any error. However when I use `Insert` statement instead of `Database.Insert` , the validation rule kick in at that time. How can I resolve this situation with Database.Insert and Validation rule. I want to only thrown the error for the records that does not meet the validation rule and pass other records which meets the validation rule. Say I am updating `30 foo__c` records using dataloader. If I use `Insert` statement, it fails all the records which I do not want. I want to fail only the ones which does not meet the validation rule. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you only create `zoo__c` records for those instances that you want them?  i.e. check first whether the `foo__c` record is open before creating the `zoo__c` record

Comment: Hmm good idea but I want to fail foo record also if I am unable to create zoo record. I am thinking may be I can put a validation rule of foo to prevent it from updating as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use addError to report the error to the parent context:

```
trigger footrigger on Foo__c (after insert,after update) {

   if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
   List<zoo__c> zlist = new List<zoo__c>();
        For(Foo__C f : trigger.new){
          Zoo__c z = new Zoo__c();
          z.Foo__c = f.id;
          z.Name='AZooObj'; 
          zlist.add(z);
        }
   Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(zlist,false);
   for(Integer index = 0, size = Trigger.new.size(); index < size; index++) {
     if(!results[index].isSuccess()) {
       Trigger.new[index].addError('Related record failed to insert with error: '+results[index].getErrors()[0].getMessage());
     }
   }
}
```

By doing this, you will not blow up an entire transaction (e.g. 200 records) when just one fails. This is ideal for when you're using the import wizard, data loader, API calls, etc, because you will be able to identify **which** record failed and why; the remainder of the records will be able to save independently when the insert does not fail.

You can read more about how the system handles partial failures in [Bulk DML Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm).

Comment: Thank you! My requirement is I do not want to update the foo record if zoo cannot be created. What if I use a validation rule on foo such that it prevents it from updating and it will also help in partial update of foo record( with its zoo record created). Any concern with this approach?

Comment: @SfdcBat This process will allow you to update 200 `Foo__c` records at once. If one of the 200 fail, the remaining 199 will still successfully update. What happens when you "addError" with "allOrNone" set to false is that the system will set aside the error records and retry the remaining records a second time. Read [Bulk DML Exception Handling](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `insert` statement to insert records then either all the records will get processed or none of them are processed.

Since you are using `Database.insert(list, false)` with `allorNone` as false, so it is not stopping you the processing of insert.

So, after insertion, you can retrieve the errors from `SaveResults` and display those errors to the users.

```
trigger footrigger on Foo__c (after insert,after update) 
{
    try
    {
       if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter)
       {
        List<zoo__c> zlist = new List<zoo__c>();
            For(Foo__C f : trigger.new){
              Zoo__c z = new Zoo__c();
              z.Foo__c = f.id;
              z.Name='AZooObj'; 
              zlist.add(z);
            }
        Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(zlist,false);

        List<String> lstErrorString = new List<String>();
        // Iterate through each returned result
            for (Database.SaveResult sr : srList) 
            {
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                    System.debug('Successfully inserted record, Id: ' + sr.getId());
                }
                else {
                    // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                    for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) 
                    {
                        lstErrorString.add(err.getMessage()); 
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!lstErrorString.isEmpty())
            {
                throw new CustomException(String.join(lstErrorString,','));
            }
       }
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new CustomException(ex.getMessage());     
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this prevent that specific Foo__c record from updating?

Comment: no it will not, your validation rule is on zoo__c. Or otherwise, you can insert master and detail in a single transaction based on externalid

Comment: According to your question you are not preventing updates on Foo__c record, you are mainly concerned about inserting Zoo__c record and displaying error message

Comment: I see your point. May be I did not mention that I do not want to update the foo record if its corresponding zoo record fails. I got an idea to use a validation rule on Foo__c itself which will prevent it from updating that specific record for which zoo cannot be created. With this I do not have to use Database.Insert method as well and Insert should be enough.

Comment: yes, that should be

Comment: This solution will break bulk data loads, and should not be used.