# Show warning message from the Case Trigger for the 6th Auth Request in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, trigger

How we can show the warning message from the trigger ? I know that its not possible using trigger, but seeking some guidance around it.

I have a trigger on `Case`, which checks if the client/requester is submitting the 5th `Authorization` request (`Authorization` is custom picklist with Yes/No values), if its a 6th request, then **at the time of Case Creation he should be see the warning message and should be able to submit the case.**

```
Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();

        for(Case cs : cases){
            if(cs.AuthorizationRequest__c == 'Yes'){
                contactIds.add(cs.ContactId);
            }
        }

        if(contactIds.size() > 0){
            List<Case> caseList = [SELECT contactId 
                                FROM Case
                               WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_QUARTER 
                                AND AuthorizationRequest__c='Yes'
                                AND ContactId IN :contactIds];

            for(Case cs : cases){
                if(cs.AuthorizationRequest__c == 'Yes' && caseList.size() > 5){
                    cs.addError('You can't put 6th Auth Request in this quarter');
                }   
            }
        }
```

Any guidance?

I have created a case something like below, but this doesn't works as expected. This does not pull any record of your code:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='Project Account');
        insert a;

        Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Test', Account=a);
        insert con;

        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();

        for(Integer i=0; i < 11; i++){
            Case c = new Case(Category__c='XXXX', SubCategory__c='CCCC', Origin='Email',
                         AuthorizationRequest='Yes',Contact=con);
            cases.add(c);
        }
```

Comment: you can refer this answer in case it helps: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187923/rolling-back-a-complete-transaction/187926#187926

Comment: Could you please share the CustomException class too ? I wonder how we are making use of thus CustomException class while showing warning to the end user and allowed the case created ?

Answer (score 0):

"should be able to submit the case" -- so you want the case to be saved?

You cannot throw a warning message but still allow the operation to complete.  If you allow the case to be inserted, then you cannot use addError or throw exceptions.

If you need to notify the user about this specific condition, then your trigger could create a task on the case and assign it to the user.

Comment: 1. Yes, I want to save the case.
2. Is there any way we can show message for workflow or process builder etc or using trigger ?

Comment: No, either the operation succeeds with no message or it fails with a message.